# QPlainText.setPlainText блокирует undo/redo

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qplaintextedit, undo-redo

Имеется подобный код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QUndoStack

class CodeField(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, w):
        super(CodeField, self).__init__(w)

        stack = QUndoStack(self)
        stack.setUndoLimit(100)
        self.undo, self.redo = stack.undo, stack.redo

    def keyPressEvent(self, e: QtGui.QKeyEvent) -> None:
        if e == QKeySequence.Undo:
            self.undo()
        if e == QKeySequence.Redo:
            self.redo()
        super(CodeField, self).keyPressEvent(e)

class CodeEditor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super(CodeEditor, self).__init__(widget)

        self.code_field = CodeField(self)
        self.code_field.textChanged.connect(self.code_changed)
    
        self.changed = False

    def code_changed(self):
        if self.changed:
            self.changed = False
            return
        text = self.code_field.toPlainText()
    
        # некоторые операции с текстом

        self.changed = True
        self.code_field.setPlainText(text)
```

---

При редактировании текста и нажатием сочетания **`undo/redo`**, ничего не происходит. 
Убираю строку `self.code_field.setPlainText(text)` в методе `code_changed()` класса `CodeEditor()`, сочетания **`undo/redo`** работают.

Перебрал все варианты, но так и не понял, от чего это зависит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QPlainTextEdit::**setPlainText**(const QString &text)
>
> Изменяет текст редактирования текста на **text** строки. Любой предыдущий текст удаляется.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - **История `undo/redo` также очищается.**  !!!
> - currentCharFormat() сбрасывается, если textCursor () уже не находится в начале документа.

Больше...  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#setPlainText